# How can I enable multiple systemd unit files with the same instance specifier?

Tags: systemd

Whenever I enable a certain instanced systemd service, I want two timers with the same instance specifier to be enabled as well. This is what my unit file *foo@.service* looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=Does something cool
Documentation=man:foo(1)

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/foo %i
PIDFile=%t/foo/foo.pid
StandardOutput=journal

[Install]
WantedBy=network-online.target
Also=bar1@%i.timer
Also=bar2@%i.timer
```

Running `systemctl enable foo@test.service` returns:

```
Failed to enable unit: Invalid argument
```

If I remove the instance specifiers from the [Install] section and replace them with specific instance names (so it looks like the following), then it works just fine.

```
...
Also=bar1@test.timer
Also=bar2@test.timer
```

The man page *systemd.unit(5)* says that the *%i* specifier is interpreted in the install section, so what gives?

```
The following specifiers are interpreted in the Install section: %n, %N, %p, %i, %U, %u, %m, %H, %b, %v.
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug with systemd that reproduces for the `Also` directive in `[Install]` section.

However there is a workaround you can use that gives you the same functionality.

Assume you have `foo@.service` file and you want a corresponding units file. Add the clause in the `WantedBy` directive instead. Enable the `.timer` units first with `systemctl enable bar1@test.timer` etc.

```
[Install]
WantedBy=network-online.target bar1@%i.timer bar2@%i.timer
```

The above works well to start multiple mpd services via socket activation using a service template and several socket files.